# Переводы ngettext, за что отвечают строки перевода

Tags: django, gettext, перевод

Впервые использовал ngettext для переводов и наткнулся на такой вывод в файле `.po`

```
#: app/admin.py:53 app/admin.py:127
msgid "task"
msgid_plural "tasks"
msgstr[0] "задача"
msgstr[1] "задача"
msgstr[2] "задача"
msgstr[3] "задача"
```

Кто подскажет, за что отвечает каждая из `msgstr` ?

Comment: За разные варианты перевода для разного количества чего-то (задач в данном случае): https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gettext#%D0%9C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0_2

Comment: В самом верху файла есть Plural-Forms, там подписано, какой индекс к какому диапазону чисел относится

Comment: спасибо. писал ответ 10 минут, не видел комментарии

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Почитав различные источники, выяснил, что числа в `[]` указывают на случай, когда число принимает то или иное значение. Указывается в начале файла в формате

```
"Plural-Forms: nplurals=4; plural=(n%10==1 && n%100!=11 ? 0 : n%10>=2 && n"
"%10<=4 && (n%100<12 || n%100>14) ? 1 : n%10==0 || (n%10>=5 && n%10<=9) || (n"
"%100>=11 && n%100<=14)? 2 : 3);\n"
```

А значит

- `0` - `n%10==1 && n%100!=11` - единичное число
- `1` - `n%10>=2 && n%10<=4 && (n%100<12 || n%100>14)` - числа заканчиваются на цифры от 2 до 4 вне диапазона 12-14
- `2` - `n%10==0 || (n%10>=5 && n%10<=9) || (n%100>=11 && n%100<=14)`- для 0 или от 5 до 9 или от 11 до 14
- `3` - остальные варианты

т.е. для русского языка надо перевести как

```
#: app/admin.py:53 app/admin.py:127
msgid "task"
msgid_plural "tasks"
msgstr[0] "задача" # 1 зачача
msgstr[1] "задачи" # 2,3,4 задачи
msgstr[2] "задач"  # 5 задач
msgstr[3] "задач"  # хз сколько задач
```

Comment: Лично я вручную заменяю бессмысленный nplurals=4 на старый и правильный для русского языка nplurals=3 https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/26123

Comment: А есть настройки, чтобы автоматически подставлялся новый вариант для `Plural-Forms` место старого формата?

Comment: Похоже нет, увы